# Updating localStorage Dynamically with inputfield with button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Basically I am using the below snippet supplied by madalin (great user), and it's looping through my localStorage. I've got a system where I can add companies to the localStorage, I just need to be able to change the value of the `sCompanies.name in the code shown below. I hope this isn't too much of a problem, thanks! :) <3

First of all I am using some code that another user madalin posted long ago that I want to adapt:

```
<div class="parent">
<select class="form-control" id="ex2" name="key"></select><br>
<input class="form-control" id="ex21" type="text" placeholder="Enter the updated value"><br>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"    onClick="editValue();">Enter</button>
</div>


 for (var i = 0; i < localStorage.length; i++) {
    $('#ex2').append('<option value="'+localStorage.key(i)+'">'+localStorage.key(i)+'</option>');
  };

function editValue() {
   var key = $(this).closest('.parent').find('option:selected').val();
  localStorage.setItem(key,$(this).closest('.parent').find('input[type="text"]').val());
}
```

My project below sorry for size :(

HTML:

```
<div id="CompanyDIV">
<h3> Add companies to localStorage here </h3>

<input id="txtCompanyName" type="text" placeholder="company name">
<input id="txtCompanyPrice" type="text" placeholder="company price">
<button id="btnAddCompany">Add Company</button>
<input id="txtSearch" type="text" placeholder="search">
<button id="btnShowHide">Show / Hide</button>

<h3> Update Values in localStorage here </h3>

<div class="parent">
    <select class="form-control" id="ex2" name="key"></select><br>
    <input class="form-control" id="ex21" type="text" placeholder="Enter the updated value"><br>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"    onClick="editValue()">Enter</button>
</div>

<h3> Data pulled from localStorage</h3>

    <div class="bs-example" data-example-id="hoverable-table"> 
        <table class="table table-hover"> 
            <thead> 
                <tr> 
                    <th>#</th> 
                    <th>Unique ID </th> 
                    <th>Company Name</th> 
                    <th>Company Price</th>
                </tr> 
            </thead> 
            <tbody id="lblCompanies"> 
            </tbody> 
        </table> 
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Jquery / localStorage

```
 if(localStorage.sCompanies == null){ var aCompanies = new Array();} 
    else{ var serelization = localStorage.getItem("sCompanies"); 
    var aCompanies = JSON.parse(serelization); } 

$("#btnAddCompany").click(function() {
  var sCompanyId = new Date().getTime();
  var sCompanyName = $("#txtCompanyName").val();
  var sCompanyPrice = $("#txtCompanyPrice").val();

  //<!------------------------------ Set interval random company price for all unique id's -->

  setInterval(function() {
    $("#lblCompanies").empty();

    for (var i = 0; i < aCompanies.length; i++) {
      var randomnumber2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * aCompanies[i].price * 10) + 1;
      // negative or positive
      randomnumber2 *= Math.floor(Math.random() * 2) == 1 ? 1 : -1;
      aCompanies[i].price = randomnumber2;
      // Updating the row  of companies
      $("#lblCompanies").append('<tr><th scope="row"  class="fa fa-trash-o fa-fw"><td class="id">' + aCompanies[i].id + ' </td></th><td>' + aCompanies[i].name + '</td><td>' + aCompanies[i].price + '</td></tr>');
    }
    // Save it on the localStorage
    localStorage.sCompanies = JSON.stringify(aCompanies);
    //showHideCompanies();

  }, 1000);

  //<!------------------------------ Set interval random company price for all unique id's ------------------------------>

  // jUser or JCompagny take the text value field up in the HTML part
  // jCompany is just an array
  // which will take values added by the user on the html for
  // which then pushes the input field data into the aCompany or aUser array

  var jCompany = {};
  jCompany.id = new Date().getTime();
  jCompany.name = sCompanyName;
  jCompany.price = sCompanyPrice;
  console.log(aCompanies);
  aCompanies.push(jCompany);
  // Save to the localStorage
  //var sFinalCompanies = JSON.stringify( aCompanies );
  // Save/update the sCompanies in localStorage
  localStorage.sCompanies = JSON.stringify(aCompanies);

  //console.log(sFinalCompanies)
});

$("#txtSearch").keyup(function() {
  // console.log("x");
  var sSearchFor = $(this).val();
  console.log(sSearchFor);

  $("#lblCompanies").children("tr").children("td:nth-of-type(1)").each(function() {
    // console.log( $(this).text() ); // Mark, Jakob
    var sCompareTo = $(this).text();
    if (sSearchFor == sCompareTo) {
      $(this).parent().css("background-color", "yellow");
    } else {
      $(this).parent().css("background-color", "white");
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: ow i meant that i tried to adapt madalin's code to mine also all of you lovely people!!

Comment: Thanks for help nnnnnn :) I appreciate it im kinda new here sorry i try my best ! :)

Comment: Down till #txtsearch is inside the #btnaddcompany


This snippet here was supposed to be in there aswell, this is above the #btnaddcompany CODE INCOMING HERE ---->






if(localStorage.sCompanies == null){
    var aCompanies = new Array();
   }
   else{
    
    var serelization = localStorage.getItem("sCompanies");
    var aCompanies = JSON.parse(serelization);
   }

Comment: OK, I've fixed the code indenting (white-space changes only) to try to make it more readable, so maybe people will find it easier to help you.

Comment: Thank you so MUCH, can you add these lines of code just below where it says Jquery / localStorage
INCOMING CODE: ------>
 if(localStorage.sCompanies == null){ var aCompanies = new Array(); } else{ var serelization = localStorage.getItem("sCompanies"); var aCompanies = JSON.parse(serelization); }

Comment: Why don't you try an [edit] yourself? For code to display properly it needs to be indented an extra four spaces, which you can do by pasting the code in, then selecting it, then clicking the `{}` button in the editor.

Comment: I did it thanks NNNNN you are my mentor :D!

Comment: Where is the onclick function editValue? Or do you want to know how to implement it?

Comment: A couple of things you could do to make this code shorter and more readable: Instead of using the array constructor `new Array()`, you should just use an array literal `[]` to create an empty array. Unless you have to support IE < 9 you can just use [`Date.now()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/now) instead of `new Date().getTime()`.